# Using Generic Type in Generator function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generator, redux-saga, typescript-generics

```js
const someFunction = function*<T extends SomeType>({ // Unexpected token, expected "("
  payload
}: SomeInterface<T>): SagaIterator {}
```

How to use generic type in generator function in React? `Unexpected token, expected "("` is thrown on `<`.

Comment: That's exactly how use use it. I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: It doesn't throw in my IDE either.. but it failed to compile when `react-scripts` start

Comment: Is that in `.ts` or `.tsx` file? Maybe it's conflicting with JSX syntax?

Comment: @ritaj Bro you can write that as an answer 

Comment: FYI it has been fixed in babel 7.9.6 (Issue: https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/11449)